# SVG Not able to find the xpath for graph elements which I required for verification in automation script

Tags: java, selenium, svg

[I want to fetch value 16.May](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrPAf.png) I am trying to automate the SVG graph and I want to get the text value so that I can verify the results, but unable to find the exact xpath for the particular element

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='rect']
```

Below is the HTML code for Graph

```
    <svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root " style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="310" height="300" viewBox="0 0 310 300"><desc>Created with Highcharts 6.1.0</desc><defs><clipPath id="highcharts-n6cxyb7-351"><rect x="0" y="8" width="9999" height="46" fill="none"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="highcharts-n6cxyb7-352"><rect x="0" y="0" width="217" height="133" fill="none"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="310" height="300" rx="0" ry="0"></rect><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="73" y="129" width="217" height="133"></rect><g class="highcharts-plot-bands-0"><path fill="#f0f4f7" class="highcharts-plot-band " d="M 73 262.5 L 290 262.5 290 196.5 73 196.5 z"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 105.5 129 L 105.5 262" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 165.5 129 L 165.5 262" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M
    226.5 129 L 226.5 262" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 287.5 129 L 287.5 262" opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 73 262.5 L 290
    262.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 73 196.5 L 290 196.5" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 73 128.5 L 290 128.5" opacity="1"></path></g><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="73" y="129" width="217" height="133"></rect><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis "><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 105.5 262 L 105.5 272" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 165.5 262 L 165.5 272" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 226.5 262 L 226.5 272" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 287.5 262 L 287.5 272" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 73
    262.5 L 290 262.5"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis "><text x="26.09375" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(270 26.09375 195.5)" class="highcharts-axis-title" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="195.5"><tspan>Mentions</tspan></text><path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 73 129 L 73 262"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group"><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 C 2.1274509803922 97.0634 20.362745098039078 86.2904 32.519607843137 86.2904 C 44.676470588235 86.2904 50.754901960784004 94.53108 62.911764705882 99.9362 C 75.06862745098 105.34132000000001 81.14705882352901 111.4008 93.303921568627 113.316 C 105.4607843137242 115.2312 111.5392156862728 115.2312
    123.69607843137 115.2312 C 135.85294117646998 115.2312 141.93137254902 85.78500000000003 154.08823529412 84.45500000000001 C 166.245098039216 83.125 172.323529411764 83.125 184.48039215686 83.125 C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634 C
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 20.362745098039078 86.2904 32.519607843137 86.2904 C 44.676470588235 86.2904 50.754901960784004 94.53108 62.911764705882 99.9362 C 75.06862745098 105.34132000000001 81.14705882352901 111.4008 93.303921568627 113.316 C 105.4607843137242 115.2312 111.5392156862728 115.2312 123.69607843137 115.2312 C 135.85294117646998 115.2312 141.93137254902 85.78500000000003 154.08823529412 84.45500000000001 C 166.245098039216 83.125 172.323529411764 83.125 184.48039215686 83.125 C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018 L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"><path fill="#8bdeb7" visibility="hidden" d="M 123 115.2312 A 0 0 0 1 1 123 115.2312 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-undefined" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="#8bdeb7" d="M 129 115.2312 A 6 6 0 1 1 128.99999700000026 115.225200001 Z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 C 2.1274509803922 97.0634 20.362745098039078 86.2904 32.519607843137 86.2904 C 44.676470588235 86.2904 50.754901960784004 94.53108 62.911764705882 99.9362 C 75.06862745098 105.34132000000001 81.14705882352901 111.4008 93.303921568627 113.316 C 105.4607843137242 115.2312 111.5392156862728 115.2312
    123.69607843137 115.2312 C 135.85294117646998 115.2312 141.93137254902 85.78500000000003 154.08823529412 84.45500000000001 C 166.245098039216 83.125 172.323529411764 83.125 184.48039215686 83.125 C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634 C
 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018 L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-2 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 132.3616 C 196.63725490196 131.02096000000031 214.87254901961 132.7074 214.87254901961 132.7074" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#c184c1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078
    132.3616 L 2.1274509803922 132.3616 C 196.63725490196 131.02096000000031 214.87254901961 132.7074 214.87254901961 132.7074 L 224.87254901961 132.7074" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-2 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"><path fill="#c184c1" visibility="hidden" d="M 93 109.459 A 0 0 0 1 1 93 109.459 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-undefined" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="#c184c1" d="M 87 103.459 L 99
    103.459 99 115.459 87 115.459 Z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-3 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 132.9468 C 2.1274509803922 132.9468 20.362745098039078 172.323529411764 133 184.48039215686 133 C 196.63725490196 133 214.87254901961 133 214.87254901961 133" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8dc63f" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078
    132.9468 L 2.1274509803922 132.9468 133 L 224.87254901961 133" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-3 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"><path fill="#8dc63f" visibility="hidden" d="M 93 133 A 0 0 0 1 1 93 133 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-undefined" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="#8dc63f" d="M 93 127 L 99 139 87 139 Z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-4 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634  C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634  214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018 L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-4 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-5 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 C 2.1274509803922 97.0634 20.362745098039078 86.2904 32.519607843137 86.2904 C 44.676470588235 86.2904 50.754901960784004 94.53108 62.911764705882 99.9362 C 75.06862745098 105.34132000000001 81.14705882352901 111.4008 93.303921568627 113.316 C 105.4607843137242 115.2312 111.5392156862728 115.2312
    123.69607843137 115.2312 C 135.85294117646998 115.2312 141.93137254902 85.78500000000003 154.08823529412 84.45500000000001 C 166.245098039216 83.125 172.323529411764 83.125 184.48039215686 83.125 C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634 C
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 20.362745098039078 86.2904 32.519607843137 86.2904 C 44.676470588235 86.2904 50.754901960784004 94.53108 62.911764705882 99.9362 C 75.06862745098 105.34132000000001 81.14705882352901 111.4008 93.303921568627 113.316 C 105.4607843137242 115.2312 111.5392156862728 115.2312 123.69607843137 115.2312 C 135.85294117646998 115.2312 141.93137254902 85.78500000000003 154.08823529412 84.45500000000001 C 166.245098039216 83.125 172.323529411764 83.125 184.48039215686 83.125 C 196.63725490196 83.125 214.87254901961 124.3018 214.87254901961 124.3018 L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-5 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-6 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634 C 2.1274509803922 97.0634 " class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634 L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-6 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-7 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 97.0634
   " class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078 97.0634 L 2.1274509803922 97.0634  L 224.87254901961 124.3018" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-7 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"><path fill="#8bdeb7" visibility="hidden" d="M 184 83.125 A 0 0 0 1 1 184 83.125 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-undefined" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="#8bdeb7" d="M 178 77.125 L 190
    77.125 190 89.125 178 89.125 Z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-8 highcharts-spline-series " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-352)"><path fill="none" d="M
    2.1274509803922 15.960000000000008  214.87254901961 111.9328" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#4fb3c3" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path><path fill="none" d="M -7.8725490196078
     L 224.87254901961 111.9328" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="rgba(192,192,192,0.0001)" stroke-width="22" class="highcharts-tracker"></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-8 highcharts-spline-series highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(73,129) scale(1 1)"><path fill="#4fb3c3" visibility="hidden" d="M 214 111.9328 A 0 0 0 1 1 214 111.9328 Z" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-undefined" fill-opacity="0.25"></path><path fill="#4fb3c3" d="M 214 105.9328 L 220 117.9328 208 117.9328 Z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" visibility="hidden"></path></g></g><text x="155" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:14px;fill:#333333;" y="21"><tspan>Mentions by Saved Search over Time</tspan></text><text x="155" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="44"></text><g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(83,35)"><rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="144" height="82" visibility="visible"></rect><g clip-path="url(#highcharts-n6cxyb7-351)"><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(8,3)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-1" transform="translate(8,19)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-2" transform="translate(8,35)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#c184c1" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Mentions</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-3" transform="translate(8,51)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8dc63f" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Online</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-4" transform="translate(8,67)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-5" transform="translate(8,83)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-6" transform="translate(8,99)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-7" transform="translate(8,115)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Exclude_Exact</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-spline-series highcharts-color-undefined highcharts-series-8" transform="translate(8,131)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" class="highcharts-graph" stroke="#4fb3c3" stroke-width="12"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"><tspan>Licensed</tspan></text></g></g></g><g visibility="visible" transform="translate(8,61)"><path fill="#cccccc" d="M 6 0 L 12 12 0 12 Z" class="highcharts-legend-nav-inactive" style="cursor:default;"></path><text x="15" y="10" class="highcharts-legend-navigation">1/5</text><path fill="#003399" d="M 36.125 0 L 48.125 0 42.125 12 Z" class="highcharts-legend-nav-active" style="cursor:pointer;"></path></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels "><text x="105.51960784314" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="281" opacity="1"><tspan>16. May</tspan></text><text x="166.30392156863" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="281" opacity="1"><tspan>18. May</tspan></text><text x="227.08823529412" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="281" opacity="1"><tspan>20. May</tspan></text><text x="279.59375" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="281" opacity="1"><tspan>22. May</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels "><text x="58" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="265" opacity="1">0</text><text x="58" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="199" opacity="1">2.5k</text><text x="58" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="132" opacity="1">5k</text></g><g class="highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip highcharts-color-undefined" style="cursor:default;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(171,-9999)" opacity="0" visibility="visible"><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 134.5 0.5 C 137.5 0.5 137.5 0.5
    137.5 3.5 L 137.5 44.5 C 137.5 47.5 137.5 47.5 134.5 47.5 L 91.5 47.5 85.5 53.5 79.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L
    134.5 0.5 C 137.5 0.5 137.5 0.5 137.5 3.5 L 137.5 44.5 C 137.5 47.5 137.5 47.5 134.5 47.5 L 91.5 47.5 85.5 53.5 79.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L
    134.5 0.5 C 137.5 0.5 137.5 0.5 137.5 3.5 L 137.5 44.5 C 137.5 47.5 137.5 47.5 134.5 47.5 L 91.5 47.5 85.5 53.5 79.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="rgba(247,247,247,0.85)" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 134.5 0.5 C 137.5 0.5 137.5 0.5
    137.5 3.5 L 137.5 44.5 C 137.5 47.5 137.5 47.5 134.5 47.5 L 91.5 47.5 85.5 53.5 79.5 47.5 3.5 47.5 C 0.5 47.5 0.5 47.5 0.5 44.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" stroke="#8bdeb7" stroke-width="1"></path><text x="8" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20"><tspan style="font-weight:bold; fill:#8bdeb7">Exclude_Exact: </tspan><tspan style="font-weight:bold" dx="0">1,875</tspan><tspan x="8" dy="15">May 21, 2019</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

[I want to get this date value
        16.may](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrPAf.png)

Comment: You want to get the value on the graph for that date? If so, you're hosed--SVG doesn't store your data

Comment: so is there any way that I can verify value?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below xpath and I am able to fetch the value

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//*[contains(@class,'highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels')]")
public static WebElement graphValues;
```